# LWC component in communities not loading properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, partner-communities, experience-builder-page

I am experiencing a very weird behavior while displaying LWC on a Opportunity record page in Communities.

I have a LWC component with the name TestLWC and I want to show it in community. So, for that I have modified the xml file with below details:

```
<targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" description="The value should be {!recordId}."/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

Now, with this, I see my TestLWC component in the community Experience Builder. Now, On Opportunity Detail page I drag and drop my component and defined the recordId property:

[image]

After that I published my changes in community. Now, I logged in as Community user and I see my Component with no issues. But if I reload my Opportunity page after some time, I don't see the Component. If I again go back to builder, I see my component is present on the page then I have to delete it and again drag and drop it then I publish again. Now, if I log in again in community I see my component, but again if I log out or refresh, I don't see my component.

Not sure, if anyone else experienced this issue. I tried clearing the cache but no luck. Is {!recordId} causing an issue? Any idea?

Comment: Does this help : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/244186/45062, or after first load it might be throwing an error. Debug it via  `Lightning debug mode` to check for component failures. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_debug_mode.htm&type=5, or via chrome developer console.

Comment: I have already defined <targetConfig> in the xml file, and I could see my component in builder. If I login to community I see the component without any issue, but If I log out or reload the screen after sometime, the component is not visible

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but I had this when i used "datasource="apex://XYZ